# logged in as admin and unable to change SA login password

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**Why can't I change the login SA credentials?**

I've logged into a windows machine using a login that is in the local admin group:

[image]

I've opened `SSMS` as administrator.

I've connected to the local instance of `SQL SERVER` using the `domain\myusername`

```
(Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2811.0 (X64) 
    Apr  6 2012 01:59:29 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
)
```

When I try to change the password for login `sa`, I am getting:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See if this can help
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/26/sql-server-fix-error-msg-15151-level-16-state-1-line-2-cannot-alter-the-login-sa-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permission/

Comment: thanks i did look at that already, nope, doesnt help

Comment: didn't occurred to me yet, but they are saying user must be in `sysadmin` server role to change sa password

Comment: right, im unable to do that

Comment: did you looked in Security->Logins->Users(RClick)->Properties->server roles that your user is assigned `sysadmin` ?

Comment: it is not assigned sysadmin, when i try to assign it, it gives me an error that i dont have permission to do this

Comment: Kind of makes sense that you should not be able assign yourself to sysadmin if you are not a sysadmin don't you think?

Comment: @Blam i totally agree. so how do i make myself sysadmin?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов, I remember there was some trick with running sqlserver in single user mode (`sqlserver -m`) and then adding admin account to `sysadmin` server role [check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You don't have a single account that can log in as a member of sysadmin role?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute following commands in the Command Prompt (change `DOMAIN\login` to yours):

```
net stop MSSQLSERVER
net start MSSQLSERVER /mSQLCMD
sqlcmd -S . -Q "if not exists(select 1 from sys.server_principals where name='DOMAIN\login') CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\login] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'DOMAIN\login', @rolename = N'sysadmin'"
net stop MSSQLSERVER
net start MSSQLSERVER
sqlcmd -S . -Q "if exists(select 1 from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```

Or if your SqlServer instance has specific name, e.g. `sql2008`:

```
set instanceName=sql2008
net stop mssql$%instanceName%
net start mssql$%instanceName% /mSQLCMD
sqlcmd -S .\%instanceName% -Q "if not exists(select 1 from sys.server_principals where name='DOMAIN\login') CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\login] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'DOMAIN\login', @rolename = N'sysadmin'"
net stop mssql$%instanceName%
net start mssql$s%instanceName%
sqlcmd -S .\%instanceName% -Q "if exists(select 1 from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```